# IE9 navigation not displaying

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a site built in Wordpress using Twitter Bootstrap. Main dropdown menu kicks in at bellow of 1200px and it works properly on Chrome, Firefox, Safari and some versions of IE. But, on IE9 (tested on Win7) it isnt showing at all.

I tried adding/including html5shiv, IE=Edge tag, everything i could think of that could make it work, but no luck.

Anybody have any advices? URL is http://tinyurl.com/oyasnfn (menu should be appearing above the slider)

Beers are on me :D

Comment: I've checked with IE tester tool and drop down is working

Comment: I've tested it for IE9 only.

Comment: @pratik, if you dont want to help, dont reply at all, okay?

numerous people told me that menu isnt shown on ie9, and when i tested it, i saw its true, so plz...
http://i.imgur.com/wDm1cyk.jpg

Comment: @pratik you shouldn't be rude its a public forum.

Comment: @KheemaPandey : sorry.

Comment: @Mariola I would suggest you instead of pasting link direct here post the code which giving you trouble. this way your question will get negative down voting..

Comment: Works on IE9 on Win7, if it is running in IE8 or 7 mode there is a bug. Due to a trailing comma in the mobilemenu.js

Comment: @Kheema, i know, but i dont think this is HTML/CSS issue, since navigation is displaying properly on other browsers, even the dropdown in the contact form works on IE9.

I am guessing this is some JS conflict, so i didnt tough that entire  HTML/CSS would be very helpful, but i think you are right

Comment: Kheema, epascarello, what tools are you using to test this? I'm running IE9 and the dropdown doesn't appear there. As I've explained in my answer, there are conditional comments that specifically hide the dropdown init code from IE9 and lower.

Comment: AHHH, you need to resize it small...Works when page is large.

Comment: I use IE tester tool. it support from I6 to IE9.

Comment: Yes, normal menu shows above the 1200px, but the dropdown that should be appearing bellow 1200 is missing

Comment: @KheemaPandey IETester isn't a reliable emulator. Use an emulation service or download virtual machines to get reliable IE version testing. [Microsoft have a handy guide for this](http://modern.ie/en-us?vsn=6d).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at line 222 of your HTML:

```
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!-->

<script src="http://rnruniversity.com/wp-content/themes/CherryFramework/js/jquery.mobile.customized.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    jQuery(function(){

        jQuery('.sf-menu').mobileMenu({defaultText: "Navigate to..."});

    });

</script>

<!--<![endif]-->
```

The script that invokes your `mobileMenu` plugin (which converts your menu into a dropdown and appends it to the header) is only invoked if the browser is either not IE, or a version of IE that higher than 9.

Remove the conditional comments and you should be fine.

Comment: Barney, thanks for your time.Just did it and still nothing :\

Comment: @Mariola try harder. If I execute that Javascript in IE9's console, the dropdown menu appears as expected. Therefore this *is* the code that generates the dropdown, and the conditional comment `<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!-->` *will* stop IE9 from executing the code unless you remove it. Try to understand what's happening here, and what you might be doing wrong.

Comment: Sh*t, my bad, didnt edited it properly, now it shows perfectly!
Thanks for help Barney!